# how to use shell variable in expect session?

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I try so send some files toward multiple servers using `scp` in bash script.
But I encountering problem.

here is the shell script I wrote.

```
#!/bin/sh

IP_LIST=('127.0.0.x' '127.0.0.y' '127.0.0.z')

for ip_addr in "${IP_LIST[@]}"
do
        echo "$ip_addr"
expect << 'EOS'
        set timeout 10
        spawn scp -p /home/foo/bar/baz.txt user@"$ip_addr":/home/destdir
        expect "*password*"
        send "pasword\r"
        expect eos
        exit 0
EOS
done
```

I assume each element in `ip_addr` is assigned to the variable `ip_addr`,
but in `expect` session, element in the list doesn't assigned.

When I execute this script, such error message appear.

```
can't read "ip_addr": no such variable  
    while executing
"spawn scp -p /home/foo/bar/baz.txt user@"$ip_addr":/home/destdir"
```

It works when use `echo` command(displays each element in `IP_LIST`).

anybody know some good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For shell's `<< STRING` syntax, if `STRING` is quoted then it'll not expand variables so your `$ip_addr` is still `$ip_addr` to the *Expect* script but it's not defined in *Expect*. You can pass the `ip_addr` from *shell* to *Expect* with the env var. E.g.:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

IP_LIST=('127.0.0.x' '127.0.0.y' '127.0.0.z')

for ip_addr in "${IP_LIST[@]}"
do
    echo "$ip_addr"
    ip_addr=$ip_addr expect << 'EOS'
      set timeout 10
      spawn scp -p /home/foo/bar/baz.txt user@$::env(ip_addr):/home/destdir
      expect "*password*"
      send "pasword\r"
      expect eos; # do you mean `eof'?
      exit 0
EOS
done
```

Comment: it works!! but I still have one question:
what does `::`  before `env(ip_addr)` mean?

Comment: `::` is used to make sure you're referencing the global `env` var. It's optional here since it's not in a *proc*. In a *proc*, if you want to use a global var you have to declare it as `global var` first or simply use `$::var`.

Answer (score -2):

Hope this helps.

```
 IP_LIST=('127.0.0.x' '127.0.0.y' '127.0.0.z')

 for ip_addr in "${IP_LIST}"
 do
         echo "$ip_addr"
 expect << 'EOS'
         set timeout 10
         spawn scp -p /home/foo/bar/baz.txt user@"$ip_addr":/home/destdir
         expect "*password*"
         send "pasword\r"
         expect eos
         exit 0
 EOS
 done
```

Comment: You just broke the array iteration.