# Expect script inside bash and resize of terminal

Tags: bash, resize, expect

I'm trying to get terminal resize working inside SSH session, that is spawned by expect, which is spawned by bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

...
SSH_PASS=XXXXX
SSH_ADDR=YYYYY

expect <(cat << EOD

    trap {
        set rows [stty rows]
        set cols [stty columns]
        stty rows $rows columns $cols < $spawn_out(slave,name)
    } WINCH
    
    spawn ssh $SSH_ADDR
    expect "Password:"
    send -- "${SSH_PASS}\n"
    interact
EOD
)
```

When terminal is resizing, I'm getting messages like

```
couldn't open (slave,name): no such file or directory
while executing
"stty rows  columns  < (slave,name)"
```

So, I assume, var `$spawn_out(slave,name)`, that is created by `expect` is not visible inside. How it could be achieved? I've tried

```
global spawn_out
```

but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I can't use SSH keys here, it's limitation I can't bypass.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40377508/900078

Comment: Take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write Expect scripts with **shell code only**. `sexpect` handles `SIGWINCH` automatically.

Comment: @pynexj I'm not sure this is the way, cause I'm not passing vars from external script to expect, it's expect itself setting those vars.

Comment: @sexpect_Expect.for.Shells thanks, will take a look. First - compiling it on OpenSUSE )

Comment: @sexpect_Expect.for.Shells Yup, your tool is working super fine, thanks! Will wait for maybe expect gurus will point me to solution without it, but as of now - many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to instead is to escape *some* of the `$` so they expanded by `expect` rather than `bash`:

```bash
SSH_PASS=XXXXX
SSH_ADDR=YYYYY

expect <(cat << EOD

    trap {
        set rows [stty rows]
        set cols [stty columns]
        stty rows \$rows columns \$cols < \$spawn_out(slave,name)
    } WINCH
    
    spawn ssh $SSH_ADDR
    expect "Password:"
    send -- "${SSH_PASS}\n"
    interact
EOD
)
```

Note that the `$SSH_ADDR` is written normally because you wish for bash to interpolate that variable. But the `rows`, `cols`, and `spawn_out` are delayed in their interpolation so that expect can do that variable evaluation instead.

---

This issue is because the `$` needs to be expanded at the right point. When you write `$rows` within the `expect <(`, it gets expanded at parse time. So the code that gets passed to `expect` is something like

```
    trap {
        set rows [stty rows]
        set cols [stty columns]
        stty rows "" columns "" < ""(slave,name)
    } WINCH
    
    spawn ssh XXXXX
    expect "Password:"
    send -- "YYYYY\n"
    interact
```

because the `rows` is undefined in the script, and gets expanded at parse time.

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it. With this change it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks! What I did actually, I've switched from expect to this one - https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect
Despite the name, actually perfect one )

Comment: No worries! By the way, just so that people can find it in the future, can you mark this as the answer because it answered your original question in the `expect` language? i.e., because `sexpect` is an alternative language altogether – which some people might not have available, such as in a cloud environment.